# Why there are four parameters for hard fork?

Tags: monerod, cryptonote, hard-fork

```
static const struct {
  uint8_t version;
  uint64_t height;
  uint8_t threshold;
  time_t time;
}
```

It is easy to understand `version` and `height`, but it is hard to understand `threshold` and `time`.
And how time is determine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explained in the Monero [source code comments](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/d850e05b53b0e6a796f157e33d338b3b8c83ce05/src/cryptonote_basic/hardfork.h#L69).

```
 * @param version the major block version for the fork
 * @param height The height the hardfork takes effect
 * @param threshold The threshold of votes needed for this fork (0-100)
 * @param time Approximate time of the hardfork (seconds since epoch)
```

Comment: It doesn't explain why.. why we need threshould?

Comment: To ensure there are enough other nodes ready and upgraded before the new fork kicks in.

Comment: It seems currently these values are set to zero initially. Does this mean currently this check is not executed before upgrade? And how the time is predicted? And how  the time parameter works? Thanks.

Comment: "It seems currently these values are set to zero initially": No, they are setup on [startup](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/c37c70f4593274e7191392ff038f6ae33f8ebe5a/src/cryptonote_core/blockchain.cpp#L393) of the daemon. "And how the time is predicted?": It's an estimate based on the fact Monero has a target block time of 2 minutes.

Comment: Threshold has been set to zero previously as none of the forks so far have been optional (no consensus/voting - they are forced upgrades).

Comment: Thanks, it there a way or formula to predict the time?

Comment: (fork height - current height) * 2 = minutes to fork

Comment: thanks. Do you know how to switch the algorithm according to the height?

Comment: Off topic for this question. SE is not suitable for long drawn out questions in comments, especially when unrelated to the original question. I suggest marking this question as answered (because it answers the question asked) then create a new question like "How can the algorithm be switched on a block height" or similar.